# widget column bug in ExtJS 6.2.1

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a treepanel with a widget column. The widget column is defined like so:

```
{
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
    width: 80,
    dataIndex: 'slider',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'slider'
    },
    onWidgetAttach: function(col, widget, rec) {
        widget.setVisible(rec.get("leaf"));
    }
}
```

So, the task is to show or hide slider widget, depending on the type of the node. If it is a leaf node, then the widget should be visible, otherwise it should be hidden. The way I do it is through `onWidgetAttach` method. But this is what I get as a result:

[image]

Please, pay attention to some leaf nodes that do not have a widget. Unfortunatelly, I can not provide a reproducible example, because of the random nature of this bug. If, for example, I refresh the panel multiple times, then in some rows widgets appear, and in some others disappear. It behaves just like a random number generator. So, what may be wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: In an attempt to reproduce this error, I created a tree with the slider widget in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tb5) - Using the exact `onWidgetAttach` you are, it seems to work fine. There must be another factor in play. Are there any errors in the console? Please compare your code to the fiddle and let me know if there are any glaring differences.

Comment: Thanks for a fiddle Jaimee. There is only one slight difference - I'm using remote data store and not inline, like in your example. But in terms of all the rest the code is absolutely identical. I have a guess of the possible reason - I know, that there is a kind of optimization in ExtJS, that widget components are somehow reused and because of this reusability, it is quite possible that when I hide widgets in a "folder" node, this widget is later rendered in other rows. For this reason, they advise not to use "render" listener when implementing this task

Comment: - if you try it, you will see, that the widget is rendered a smaller number of times, than there are rows in the panel.